# visual studio release management - configuration variable with multi-line value?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, release-management, ms-release-management

We are in the process of trying to automate our build/deploy processes with the Release Management tool for Visual Studio (formerly InCycle).

The Release Management tool includes a facility to modify settings in a web.config (or app.config).  However, there are situations where I'd like to be able to do more than this.

For example, we have URL rewriter rules to automatically redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.  But this won't work (at present) on our dev workstations.  So, the "base" version of the web.config doesn't include the rewriter rules -- they are inserted at build/publish time via a web.config transform.

But the Release Management "configuration variable" mechanism won't let me specify more than a single line as a replacement value.
I realize I can remove line breaks, and condense an XML fragment to a single line of text. But I'd rather not have a web.config with lines that are several thousand characters long.  And I suspect our IT folks -- who after all may also need to view/edit the file -- would feel rather more strongly about this than I do ;)

In general, the web.config transform mechanism had several modes: you could change a setting but also insert or replace (or delete) an entire section / XML element.  While it's nice to no longer be restricted to web.config files (out of the box), the new functionality seems to be much more limited.

Am I missing something? Has anyone else found this to be an issue? What did you do to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use xml transform to achieve what you want. Make sure that your transform are applied during your build, and the resulting web.config file available in your build output folder will be containing your URL rewriter rules. RM will pick it up from there and apply any other normal token replacement.

Here is a post that help in this regards: http://incyclesoftware.zendesk.com/entries/21487316-InRelease-with-Web-Deploy

If you have multiple stages in your release path, and for example the first stage should not have your URL rewriter section, than it may be a bit harder. You will need to apply your transform as part of your deployment. Multiple components/actions will need to be used for that (xcopy component, xml transform action/component).

I can't find it now, but I know there is some command line tool you can invoke to achieve your xml transformation as part of your deployment.

Comment: At this point, I'd rather keep the build configuration as generic as possible, i.e. keep the server/tier-specific information out of the build.  But I can see an argument for doing it the other way. I'll have to chew on that some more.

Comment: We do have multiple stages, and I'd like to keep my options open. I had started heading down the path of doing the transforms as part of the deploy.  Fortunately Microsoft has open-sourced the transformation engine - it's on [CodePlex](http://xdt.codeplex.com/) - and yes, there's a stand-alone version - [Hanselman blogged about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx), and it's also available as a NuGet package.  I'll head down that road and see where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my lack of knowledge about rewriter rules but can they exist in the base version of web.config and be set up so that they don't effectively do anything and 'rewrite' to HTTP?

If that's possible then the way I would do this is to configure a web.config.release file that will create a tokenised web.config via the transformation process. However, rather than use Web One Click Publish I use the **/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false** arguments in the TFS build definition to apply the transformation. This then results in a build in the drops folder that is completely unaware about any environment it will be deployed to. You then simply use an XCopy Deployer-based component in RM to deploy the website and replace all the tokenised values for that environment. See my blog post [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-preparing-deployment-pipeline/) for more details of the technique.

Comment: There isn't a whole lot out there on the URL rewriter module ... and some of what is out there I have found to be incorrect :(  I got something working mostly via trial and error.

Comment: What you're describing is the direction we were tentatively headed  ("generic" build, environment-specific transformations handled by RM). I'll give your blog post a look -- unfortunately the site is blocked by our firewall :(